# How to install Orbeon Form Builder on localhost

Tags: forms, tomcat, orbeon

This may seem like a very silly question, but i am so confused about installing orbeon forms on my local machine. I have downloaded the free version as i would like to try it out before i pay $1000+.

Basically I downloaded the latest version of XAMPP which comes with Tomcat on it. I then made a new folder in webapps call orbeon which i copied the orbeon.war fiel into. i then went to localhost:8080/orbeon but it comes up with oops! good chrome could not connect to localhost:8080.

Am i able to use xampp or do i have to use just Tomcat?

Any help on how to install orbeon forms would be greatly appreciated, i think what i really need is help installing whatever i have to have, to install orbeon onto.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to make the orbeon set-up work.
Step-1: Download the latest version of [Orbeon Professional Edition (PE)] (http://www.orbeon.com/download)
Step-2: Extract the downloaded orbeon.war in the webapps folder of Tomcat.
Step-3: For running the Professional edition of orbeon, you require a license.xml file which is available in the same page where you have downloaded the WAR.
Step-4: For downloading the license file you need to do  registration by filling all the mandatory fields and this license is valid for a period of 90 days.
Step-5:Once you downloaded the license.xml file, keep it in the below path of the extracted Orbeon WAR.
\webapps\orbeon\WEB-INF\resources\config
Step-6: Start the Tomcat Server and test the installation